# Kendo grid filter

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that I need to save the filter value for.  I need to save it off in temporary storage so if the user leaves the page and then returns I can reload the table with the same filter set and the same view of the grid displayed.

Example:
I'm on page grid with the filter set to show column 1 with a value of "john".  The user goes to view page "School" and returns to page grid.  I would like for the page to reload with the filter set to show the same view with "john" as the filter.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you look at the persist state demo? http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/persist-state

Comment: Thanks, that did help.  Not sure how I missed it.  One problem I have is that my filter is a dropdown list and on reload it is no longer a dropdown list.  Any suggestions.

Comment: You might have to recreate the list after loading previous state...

Comment: Is there a way just to set the value of the filter dropdown list?  If I log what is stored, I can see the value but am not sure how to access it to just set the value.